# Disable middle click from inserting whitespace character

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-14.04, cloud9-ide

Really enjoying using c9.io; one annoying issue.

I am a tab fiend and often have many tabs opening and closing (within the IDE). I tend to close these with a click of the mouse scroll wheel, a side effect of this seems to be add strange a strange character into whichever file was open at the time.

I'm not sure what it is... it appears to be some kind of space, highlighted with red and represented by a single dot.

[image]

I'm assuming this is a shortcut/keybinding of some kind.

Does anyone know:

1. What this is and what it represents?
2. How I can disable it so I can quickly nerf my tabs without fear?

Comment: I'm a dev at Cloud9. I've added this to our internal bug tracker and we'll have it fixed soon.

Comment: thanks @Tim! Good to know i'm not just nuts.

Comment: Yes, Thanks @Tim! This issue is only happening for me on my Ubuntu machine

Comment: I can confirm that this is an issue that is not reproducible on Windows 7 or Windows XP but does occur on two separate Ubuntu 14.04 systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using linux, this might be contents of secondary clipboard, Ace puts \x01 into it due to a bug.

Comment: I can confirm it was indeed a bug and now appears to be functioning fine. Thanks @Tim